# What are the right properties of kafka producer API 0.9.0.0

Tags: kafka-producer-api

Recently I am working on Kafka Producer API to produce compressed messages on wire. In Apache kafka wiki document https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compression, it is mentioned that we have to use two producer properties as;

- compression.codec
- compressed.topics

**Problem:**

After reading the above I straight went to send compressed messages from kafka-producer-API. After a lot of tries I was unable to send a compressed message. When I dig the producer API in depth, I came to know that the API is using ProducerConfig.java class. In this class I found the following compression property;

- `public static final String COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG = "compression.type";`

It is very obvious that this property is compression.type not compression.codec.
Secondly I was unable to find second property "compressed.topics" that was mentioned in document. So I am unable to specify compression topics.

What is the wrong, API or document and how I can specify list of topics for compression using API.

Comment: http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/clients/producer.html#configuration

Comment: Or maybe: http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/clients/producer.html